# How to show a drop-down list with a pre-selected option

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to update my form when I click edit button then all info is showing correctly but status value is showing all time same open option. I dont know why it is showing same open status and my currently status is **done** but it is showing all time **open** please help me to fix this issue thanks

this is my form code username is showing correctly but status is not showing correct

```
 <p><label class="field" for="username">UserName:</label>
     <input name="username" type="text" id="username"  value="<?php echo $username; ?>" size="50" />
   </p>
  <p>

                <label class="field" for="Status">Status</label>
                    <select name="status" id="status" value="<?php echo $status; ?>"  >
                        <option value="open">Open</option>
                        <option value="done">Done</option>
                        <option value="pending">Pending</option>
                        <option value="working">Working</option>
                    </select>
       </p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `selected` attribute.

```
<select name="status" id="status">
    <option value="open" <?php if($status=="open") { echo "selected"; } ?> >Open</option>
    <option value="done" <?php if($status=="done") { echo "selected"; } ?> >Done</option>
    <option value="pending" <?php if($status=="pending") { echo "selected"; } ?> >Pending</option>
    <option value="working" <?php if($status=="working") { echo "selected"; } ?> >Working</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @user2938105 what value you are getting in `$status`?

Comment: if you getting open than the first record will selected.. simple

Comment: if its status is done, so it will select 2nd option.

Comment: no i dont want select any opption all data coming to mysql so if data status is done then it will show done status and status is pending then it will show pending undertand

Comment: @user2938105 yeah, same code.. i think you are getting wrong status from database

Comment: spelling mistake in my datbase Done and in code done so Captial letter mistake thanks you

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong way, correct way is to use like this,

```
<select name="status">
<?php
$options = array("open","done","pending","working");
$selected = "done";
foreach($options as $option){
    if($selected==$option){
        echo '<option value="'.$option.'" selected="selected">'.ucfirst($option).'</option>';
    }else{
        echo '<option value="'.$option.'">'.ucfirst($option).'</option>';
    }
}
?>
    </select>
```

Comment: dear it is showing now done status but i have many query in mysql some time status is pending some time status is open so i want to show mysql status here if mysql data status is done then it will show done if mysql data status is open then it will show open understand what i mean

Comment: ok, email / chat with me at web2students.com@gmail.com if i were online i will chat else email you but i may take time in replying if i were busy

Comment: Heading of question is, "how to show correct value in select change" and tags are javascript, php, mysql. This is mis-leading. It's looks like javascript's on change event. It should be changed to something like, "How to show a drop-down list with a pre-selected option"

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to embed the status in the options tag, you should use the 'selected' attribute for selection of the  tag options. Here is your modified code with correct handling:-

```
<p><label class="field" for="username">UserName:</label>
 <input name="username" type="text" id="username"  value="<?php echo $username;?>"       size="50" />
 </p>
 <p>

            <label class="field" for="Status">Status</label>
                <select name="status" id="status" >
                    <option value="open" <?php echo $status == 'open' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Open</option>
                    <option value="done" <?php echo $status == 'done' ? 'selected' : '' ;?>>Done</option>
                    <option value="pending" <?php echo $status == 'pending' ? 'selected' : '' ; ?>>Pending</option>
                    <option value="working" <?php echo $status == 'working' ? 'selected' : '' ; ?>>Working</option>
                </select>
   </p>
```

Comment: dhunju ur code is showing only open status i have done status and pending status in my data so it is showing pending status correctly but it is not update other status correct

Comment: dhunju now i solve a problem... spelling mistake in my datbase Done and in code done so Captial letter mistake thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You need selected tag. Modify your form like this

```
<select name="status" id="status"> <!-- value removed, there's no use of it here -->
    <option value="open" <?php if ($status=="open") {echo "selected"}?>>Open</option>
    <option value="done" <?php if ($status=="done") {echo "selected"}?>>Done</option>
    ....
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use selected attribute for option.

Change your code as

```
<select name="status" id="status">
  <option value="open" <?php selected($status, 'open'); ?>>Open</option>
  <option value="done" <?php selected($status, 'done'); ?>>Done</option>
  <option value="pending" <?php selected($status, 'pending'); ?>>Pending</option>
  <option value="working" <?php selected($status, 'working'); ?>>Working</option>
</select>

<?php
function selected( $selected_value, $value ) {
   if( $selected_value === $value ) {
      echo 'selected=true';
   }
}
?>
```